# Cannot see form designer in MonoDevelop/Quantal Quetzal

Tags: 12.10, gtk, monodevelop

I'm running Quantal Quetzal, and installed MonoDevelop from Synaptic, also gtk-sharp2.

Synaptic installed MonoDevelop 3.0.3.2.

Everything working fine in the IDE with one exception: When I create a gtk# 2.0 project, I cannot see the form designer in the IDE. I can build the project and run it and the winform launches, but in the designer I can see only source code, not the GUI designer, when I open the MainWindow unit, even though view is set to Visual Design. I must be missing a package?

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing that needs to be installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the entire MonoDevelop installation from Synaptic and installed from Software Center, which installed the same version of MonoDevelop: 3.0.3.2. Works fine now.

Synaptic is very powerful and shows more than Software Center, but requires detailed knowledge of all required packages to use properly.

I also tried installing with apt-get on top of the Synaptic installation, but it found nothing missing and nothing to do.